# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null even image exists

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, fileoutputstream

Saving the file:

```
FileOutputStream fo = null; 
try { 
        fo = this.openFileOutput("test.png", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fo)
```

Loading the file:

```
String fname = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/test.png"; 
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fname);
i.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

The last line gives a null pointer exception, why is BitmapFactory.decodeFile returning null? I can verify that the file is getting saved correctly as I can pull it using adb and see the png displaying properly.

Comment: Have you closed the file output stream? What is "i" set to, and why does it have a single character name?

Comment: Yes it's closed. i was an image view, which was set to null, because I referenced it incorrectly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the `NullPointerException` is directly on this line:

> i.setImageBitmap(bMap);

Then your problem is that `i` is `null`. Given that you're calling setImageBitmap(), I am guessing that `i` is an `ImageView` -- make sure your `findViewById()` call is working.

Also, you should use the following to get `fname`:

> String fname=new File(getFilesDir(), "test.png").getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score 2):

When using the options parameter in the DecodeFile method be sure that the **InJustDecodeBounds** property is set to **false** or otherwise it will always return null. This can be set to true when you just want the file to be decoded but you don't need it further in your app/code. This way no extra memory needs to be allocated. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for an example.