# Android: decodeFile always returns null for file in internal storage

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I have a file saved locally into the application's private storage. I have verified it exists, however whenever I call `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` it always returns `null`.

If I save the file as a resource and use `ImageView.setImageResource`, it always shows up fine.

What is the problem?

Here is the snippet:

```
filename = "test.png";

if (doesFileExist(filename))
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
```

I've also tried:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getFilesDir().getPath()
                    + filename);
```

Comment: In decodeFile() you have to pass full pah of the file not just the name or not the way you are trying

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This question has been answered before such as here:
[BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null even image exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388898/bitmapfactory-decodefile-returns-null-even-image-exists)

This was exactly what I needed:

```
String fname=new File(getFilesDir(), "test.png").getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: you SHOULD answer your own question. I landed on this question with the same problem and got the solution from you. The question you reference as having the answer wasn't in my initial search either. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using BitmapFactory.decodeFile, try using InputStream:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){          
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```

Answer (score 3):

Folks, files stored in app resource should be referenced in special way. E.g. if file is located in assets and named as "myfile.png" it has to be referenced as:

```
String uriString="file:///android_asset/myfile.png";
Uri uri=Uri.parse(uriString);
```

Comment: Good info to know, but in this case, the file is downloaded into the app's private storage and not in the resources.

Answer (score 3):

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile` expects a file path without the scheme. I.e. without the `file://` in the beginning.

If you're handling a Uri, don't just `.toString()` it, but instead call `.getPath()` on it, and pass that to the method.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the required permissions (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

You need to add this line to manifests:
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try fileList()? It

> returns an array of strings naming the
>   private files associated with this
>   Context's application package.

Comment: Actually, I used that to verify the file does in the Logcat output.  So, the file is there.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was getting image from locally saved URL something like "file:///storage/emulated/0/...." (I have used Phonegap plugin to capture image. Plugin was giving me image path, which I need to use in native code)

Here is the code snippet which worked for me.

```
String captured_image_info = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.testapp/cache/1493809796526.jpg"
Uri uri=Uri.parse(captured_image_info);
largeLog("uri", "" + uri);

InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object

byte[] decodedBytes = baos.toByteArray();

Bitmap img_captured_image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup run-time permissions for Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
If you don't you'll get a null without getting any error message or even an indication in the Log.
Note that you need to request the permissions both in the Manifest and at run time.