# BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returns null

Tags: android, file, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am creating an Android app in which you  copy an image from location `x` to location `y`. After the copying is complete I would like to see the picture in a `ImageView`. 
I know the images location, but no matter what I try I can't create a `bitmap` object of it.

The line which are causing my problems is this:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dir+s);
```

`dir = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/images/";`

`s = file name (eg. 1275123123.jpg)`

If I create a `File` object with the same path, and call `f.isFile()`, it returns `true`.

Opening the image in either android or windows are not a problem.

Comment: what`s the real path?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013029/android-decodefile-always-returns-null-for-file-in-internal-storage

Comment: @blackbelt /data/data/net.hath.snapcap/cache/images/file.jpg

Comment: @Ryan I tried it just now, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Didn't you forget to add SD card access permissions READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and what eventually solved it was creating `FileInputStream(...)` and decoding the stream. This is the code I used, I changed it to suite your case:

```
File location = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/images");
File dest = new File(location, fileName + ".JPG");
FileInputStream fis;
fis = new FileInputStream(dest);
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

Comment: I'm getting FileNotFoundException no creating fis. While File object is fine. Please help

Comment: No need to do this. `decodeFile` calls `decodeStream` itself:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#BitmapFactory.decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score -1):

You have to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

permissions to you manifest.

And please don't forget to request runtime permission from user.