# BitmapFactory.decodeFile in asset doesn't work (FileNotFindException)

Tags: android, bitmapfactory, android-assets

I don't know why `decodeFile` doesn't work when the **param** point to a file inside asset folder.

```
     // Load images from the file path
    String[] dir = null;
    try {
        dir = GenericMainContext.sharedContext.getAssets().list("drawable");
       // dir Log => [ic.png, ic_info_dark.png, ic_launcher_default.png]
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (String uri : dir){ 
        // do your stuff here
        if (uri!=null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///android_asset/drawable/"+uri);               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Any explanation ?

Comment: *Any explanation ?* yes, `fileName` doesn't exist in assets ...

Comment: I checked the `fileName` exist ;)

Comment: no, it doesn't ... I got more rep ... I win ... or you will prove that it exists ...

Comment: get look here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7MJlMguOqDzX014YXJNb0FTNVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013029/android-decodefile-always-returns-null-for-file-in-internal-storage

Comment: @Abdellah one more thing ... show us what is in the `fileName` before you called your code ... also where are you using it? as a field? or in some method ? method of what class?

Comment: you know that `GenericMainContext.getContext().xxxx` may trow NPE then bitmap will be null ? .... my guess is that the all is because `GenericMainContext.sharedContext` and `GenericMainContext.getContext()` .... instead of using context passed via parameter ...

Comment: I have 2 years of experience I think I will not miss this ;)

Comment: Don't prefix with `file:///android_asset/`, use use `getAssets().open("drawable/"+uri)` @Abdellah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file:///android_asset/` is used by WebView to load assets. To load assets programmatically use the `getAssets()` method which returns an `AssetMAnager` on a `Context` object such as an `Activity`. The `open(filename)` will return a `InputStream` to your asset file. The following will create a `Bitmap` from your asset file `fileName` inside an `Activity`,

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open(fileName))
```

Comment: Nothing changed same result bitMap `null`

Comment: Don't prefix with `file:///android_asset/`, use use `getAssets().open("drawable/"+uri)` @Abdellah