# Android startActivityForResult trying to fecth Image from Gallery Error

Tags: android

I am trying to get  image from gallery  and this is my code.

```
 mProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent i = new Intent(
                         Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                 startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);//Result_Load_Image =1
             }
         });



 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap bm =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 100, 100, true);
            mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(ProfilePicture.addPicture(resized));

        }


    }
```

and this my ImageConvertor code

```
    public class ProfilePicture {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap() {
        Bitmap result = null;
        try {
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

            int color = 0xff424242;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));




        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
        }
        return result;
    }



      public static Bitmap addPicture(Bitmap bitmap){
          Bitmap result = null;
          try {
              result = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
              Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

              int color = 0xff424242;
              Paint paint = new Paint();
              Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);

              paint.setAntiAlias(true);
              canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
              paint.setColor(color);
              canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);
              paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

          } catch (NullPointerException e) {
          } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
          }
          return result;
      }

}
```

This is my log

```
31696-31696/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: moirai.com.moirai, PID: 31696
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/mediakey:/AF1QipNJLOnQ-ATM0T7KBDkqc9PUPn2l7zM4L59fsoMv/ORIGINAL/NONE/1079070800 flg=0x1 (has clip) }} to activity {moirai.com.moirai/moirai.com.moirai.RegisterNow}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3607)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3650)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:591)
at moirai.com.moirai.RegisterNow.onActivityResult(RegisterNow.java:312)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3603)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3650) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

The problem is when i start the app and click on `ImageView` it starts the gallery, But when i select any Image , The app stops immediately. Can someone please tell me What is wrong with my code. ThankYou.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: decodeFile always returns null for file in internal storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013029/android-decodefile-always-returns-null-for-file-in-internal-storage)

Comment: Hey i am trying to get the image throught content provider. so how do i get the file name ??

Comment: How can i  get the selected image name?

Comment: Could you follow this answer please http://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175/4281182

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you get a Bitmap's width at somewhere in your code.

NullPointerException:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

try this code onActivityresult

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_CODE && responseCode == RESULT_OK && null != intent) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        mImageCaptureUri = intent.getData();
        System.out.println("Gallery Image URI : "+mImageCaptureUri);
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```