# BitmapFactory's decodeFile returns null

Tags: android, appium, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

This is a simplified version of my code. I get two screenshot of the app screen and store in first.png and sec.png which I can see is located in the app\src folder. I can open the images and see that they are correct screenshots. However when I try to get them into bitmap using bitmapfactory I get null. I've tried giving absolute path and also relative path and I've followed other identical question responses so please have a look at it before marking it as duplicate.

```
class Test{
private static boolean compareImages() throws FileNotFoundException {
    ​Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("src/"+imgFirst);
    Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("src/"+imgSecond);
    if (bitmap1.getWidth() != bitmap2.getWidth() ||
            bitmap1.getHeight() != bitmap2.getHeight()) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap1.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap1.getWidth(); x++) {
            if (bitmap1.getPixel(x, y) != bitmap2.getPixel(x, y)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
 public static boolean test() {

    File scrFile = (Setup.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);//The Setup.getDriver() returns an AppiumDriver.
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(imgFirst));
    scrFile = (Setup.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(imgSecond));
    if(compareImages())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
 }
    private static String imgFirst = "first.png";
    private static String imgSecond = "sec.png";
 }
```

Comment: in your code where is the `BitmapFactory` imported?

Comment: I've imported `android.graphics.Bitmap` and
`android.graphics.BitmapFactory`

Comment: okay, could you add the stacktrace of the exception you are getting

Comment: Show the code where you store the screenshot in the disk. You should be able to use the same path to retrieve the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a `NPE` on `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` you should try getting the absolute path of your file and use it as :

```
String firstImage=new File(getFilesDir(), imgFirst).getAbsolutePath();
​Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(firstImage);
```

Referenced : [SO-3388898](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388898/bitmapfactory-decodefile-returns-null-even-image-exists?lq=1)